# breeze: pagination on expand

Tags: pagination, breeze

Is it possible to do the following with Breeze ?

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Mandates").where("Id", "==", mandatId)
        .expand("OpenPositions").skip(offset).take(pageSize).inlineCount(true);
```

I would like the paging to occur on the OpenPositions collection but instead it's applied to the Mandates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible without seeing your schema but why not query on "OpenPositions"? i.e. something like

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("OpenPositions")
    .where("Mandate.Id", "==", mandatId)
    .expand("Mandate").skip(offset).take(pageSize).inlineCount(true);
```